# Magento SQL Statement to Set Sale price based on percentage of Regular price

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I am using Magento Store Manager, which allows to edit multiple products using SQL statements. An example give for increasing the current value by 10% (of the regular price, for example):

```
[FIELD_VALUE]*1.1
```

Currently, the products I am editing do not have a value set for sale price, thus, I need the statement to first retrieve the regular price, and then alter it by reducing by 5%.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
UPDATE products SET salesPrice = RegularPrice * 0.95
```

I don't know the field names, so you'll need to update table and field names above

Comment: I have the field id's for salesprice (65) and regular price (64)